# When using hyperref and pdfbookmarks, how do I remove or override a pdfbookmark from a section?

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I'd like my bibliography and appendix bookmarks to appear at the top level of my bookmarks hierarchy.  So behind the `\bibliography` command, I placed:

```
\pdfbookmark[-1]{Bibliography}{bibliography}
```

which worked, but it still adds the default bibliography bookmark to the hierarchy underneath the new one.

So how can I either reassign the level of the default one, or remove it entirely and replace with the new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the `bookmark` package with its `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}` command. Probable duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2742/appendices-in-pdf-outline-appear-as-childs-of-last-section).

Comment: golden..  not sure if it was a duplicate, but their answer of adding  \cleardoublepage and \phantomsection  helped with bookmarks going to the wrong biblio page.  Thanks!