# Glossary and list of figures have the same page number in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, glossaries, acronyms

In my table of contents the glossary and the list of figures have the same page number. However, these two areas are not on the same page. Can anyone help me to get the correct number of pages set?

My glossary is called "Akronyme" because it is in German.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=dontgroup]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}
\listoffigures
```

Comment: There would be another way... Are you using the package `hyperref`?

Comment: Yipp! I use it on the top of my document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issuing of

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}
```

comes too soon, since `\listoffigures` sets a new chapter (perhaps starred) that initiates itself with a page break. Inserting this page break as `\clearpage` before `\addcontentsline` flushes all unprocessed floats, inserts the appropriate page for the ToC while avoiding the default `\clearpage` issued by `\chapter` (from `\listoffigures`). So, your document structure should instead resemble:

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=dontgroup]
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}
\listoffigures
```

If you're running in `twoside` mode use `\cleardoublepage`.

The above suggestion should work for most document classes.

Answer (score 1):

To extend @Werner's answers I come about the case that using `\cleardoublepage` (or `\clearpage`) did not help. Here the package "hyperref" is apparently involved. Page references could still be wrong because the command `\addcontentsline` refers to a wrong location. The [documentation of the package "hyperref"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) states

> `\addcontentsline` refers to the latest previous location where an anchor is set.

This behavior can be corrected by using `\phantomsection`.

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=dontgroup]
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}
\listoffigures
```

See also: [When do I need to invoke \phantomsection?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44088/24449) or [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2744/24449).